# Average Manhattan Distance on a Hypercube

Tags: probability, geometry

How does the average Manhattan ($L1$) distance between any two vertices of the $1$-hypercube scale with its dimension? (i.e., what is this distance as a function of the dimension $n$).

Comment: Each pair of entries differ by $1$ or coincide with equal probability hence the mean $L^1$ distance equals $\frac{n}2$.

Comment: Thanks @Did. That's an elegant answer :)

Comment: @Did, actually there is an interpretation issue here: what I meant in the OP was the average distance of any two vertices which are different, and ordering does not count (which I think is the natural meaning of average distance of points). Hence, under this interpretation, for $n=1$ the average distance is $1$, not $1/2$; and for $n=2$ it is $4/3$, not $1$.

Comment: Then, $$\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}\cdot\frac{n}2=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.$$

Comment: @Did, thanks again. What we now realize is that it is asymptotically $n/2$, after all.... (converging to it very fast).

Answer (score 2):

Let one vertex be $\mathbf{0}$ without loss of generality. Then there are clearly $\binom{n}{k}$ vertices at distance $k$ (just look at the hamming distance of the coordinates of the other point from $\mathbf{0}$), so the average distance between two vertices is
$$\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_k k \binom{n}{k}.$$

Comment: Thanks Eric, but that seems to me to describe the average distance only from a single vertex (0). One has to average over all vertices, without double counting. Also, the normalization $2^n$ seems wrong...

Comment: @Omri This is the answer (none of your objections apply) and the result can be computed explicitely, see my comment on main.

Comment: @Eric, please see above my comment to Did.